# Expose Attached Property in the Visual Studio Properties Window

Tags: c#, wpf

For my project I'm adding an attached property to my controls using `DependencyProperty`.

It works, but I would like to have my property exposed in the VisualStudio Properties Window.

I'm not creating any `UserControl`, because I want all my standard controls to have this property.
Also, I don't want to use the existing `Tag` property as in the future I will have more properties to add.

Is this possible? How it can be done?

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_CustomPropertyTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_CustomPropertyTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1" local:Extensions.MyTestProp="Hello 1!" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="36,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" />
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2" local:Extensions.MyTestProp="Hello 2!" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="36,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My code-behind:

```
using System.Windows;
namespace Wpf_CustomPropertyTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Extensions.GetMyTestProp((UIElement)sender));
        }
    }

    public class Extensions
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTestPropProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyTestProp", typeof(string), typeof(Extensions), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public static void SetMyTestProp(UIElement element, string value)
        {
            element.SetValue(MyTestPropProperty, value);
        }
        public static string GetMyTestProp(UIElement element)
        {
            return (string)element.GetValue(MyTestPropProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512860.aspx

Comment: @AjS, this is for Domain-Specific Languages. I don't see how it can help.